# is there more elegant way to declare new var and use global at the same time

Tags: go

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

var test string
func main() {
    // var err error
    // test, err = returnString()
    test, err := returnString()
    if err != nil {
        // something
    }
    fmt.Println(test)
    testGlobal()
}

func returnString() (string, error) {
    return "foo", nil
}

func testGlobal() {
    fmt.Println(test)
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/BfSh8ANAbDi

Basically I have global var `test` and I have a function that returns `string, error`, now I want to declare `err` variable and use global variable `test`. I can declare `var err error` in the function but I am wondering if there is more elegant way of doing this.

Comment: If you don't like the `var err error` statement, the only alternative I can think of is to assign the result to a uniquely named variable in the local scope and then, after the error check, assign its value to the global one. Whether or not this is stylistically more elegant is subjective.

Comment: its not that I don't like, Im was just wondering if that is proper gopher way, seams like it is, thanks!

Comment: "elegant global variable" seems like a contradiction

Comment: The topic is elegance, and using a global variable makes elegance unachievable. No sarcasm involved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I am wondering if there is more elegant way of doing this.

No, there isn't.